# How to create a file from Wscript.Echo strLine

Tags: vbscript, wsh

Just starting with VBScript:

This script retrieves a file path from a text file and displays the output on the screen:

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("c:\temp\log.txt", ForReading)
Const ForReading = 1
Dim arrFileLines()
i = 0
Do Until objFile.AtEndOfStream
Redim Preserve arrFileLines(i)
arrFileLines(i) = objFile.ReadLine
i = i + 1
Loop
objFile.Close
For Each strLine in arrFileLines
WScript.Echo strLine
Next
```

WScript.Echo strLine displays the name of the file on the screen

Is there a way to create a file of the same name as the value contained in strLine ?

I have tried running:

```
cscript vbscript > strLine
```

but it only creates a file called "strLine" rather than the file that is stored in strLine

any assistance appreciated

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Set tsX = objFS.CreateTextFile(strLine, True)` - after reading about this method in [the docs.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5t9b5c0c%28v=vs.84%29.aspx)

**Update:**

In code:

```
Option Explicit
Dim goFS : Set goFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim tsNames : Set tsNames = goFS.OpenTextFile("fnames.txt")
Do Until tsNames.AtEndOfStream
   Dim tsX : Set tsX = goFS.CreateTextFile(tsNames.ReadLine())
   tsX.WriteLine "Abracadabra"
   tsX.Close
Loop
tsNames.Close
```

Comment: I added that to the bottom of the script as follow:


    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")



    Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("c:\temp\log.txt", ForReading)
    Const ForReading = 1


    Dim arrFileLines()


    i = 0


    Do Until objFile.AtEndOfStream


    Redim Preserve arrFileLines(i)


    arrFileLines(i) = objFile.ReadLine


    i = i + 1


    Loop


    objFile.Close


    For Each strLine in arrFileLines


    WScript.Echo strLine
    Next
    DIM objFS
    Set tsX = objFS.CreateTextFile(strLine, True)

But I must be still missing something ?

Comment: I'll try this tomorrow and let you know how I go

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the echoed value you could do something like this in `cmd`:

```
for /f "tokens=*" %f in ('cscript //NoLogo vbscript') do @(
  if not exist "%~dpf" md "%~dpf"
  if not exist "%~ff" type nul>"%~ff"
)
```

Comment: Just tried this. Running vbs script from c:\apps and getting the following:

 A subdirectory or file c:\apps\ already exists.
 The filename, directory name or volume label syntax is incorrect

It has created a file called "Copyright Microsoft Corporation....."
in c:\apps

Comment: That's the logo message. Run `cscript.exe` with the option `//NoLogo` to suppress it.

Answer (score 0):

Just one line is needed:

```
Set file = objFSO.CreateTextFile("C:\Temp\" & strLine)    ' & extension - if needed eg .txt
```

Change the path as needed

Add text to the file by:

```
file.WriteLine    Line           'line by line
```

Or if you have complete text:

```
file.Write        CompleteText
```

And don't forget to close the file when done

```
file.close
```